# Intersection of Ideal in Gap(QPA)

Tags: gap

I'm New to Gap(QPA). I'm trying to intersect Ideal in Gap and find their generators. For example here I construct some trivially intersecting ideals,

Q:= Quiver(1,[[1,1,"a"],[1,1,"b"]]);;

kQ:=PathAlgebra(Rationals,Q);;

f1:=RightIdeal(kQ,[a]);;

f2:=RightIdeal(kQ,[b]);;

I:=RightIdeal(kQ,[a^2]);;

Intersection(f1,f2);

Intersection(f1,I);

This returns:

Error, no method found! For debugging hints type ?Recovery from NoMethodFound

Error, no 2nd choice method found for `IsFiniteDimensional' on 1 arguments at.....

As I $\cap$ f1 should give me back I.

How does one do this properly?

Comment: This kind of question about specific software is not really for MSE. I would recommend asking the QPA developers, they even offer an issue tracker on GitHub that you could use for it. It looks like this feature is simply not available (and in general computing intersections of ideals in non-commutative rings is difficult, though perhaps in this context it's not, I don't know, I would ask them)